# How can I load non-RDF XML files into Virtuoso?

Tags: xml, database, virtuoso

I'm seeing some Virtuoso documentation pages that mention its capabilities with XML, and I even read that Virtuoso is a "native-XML" database. Yet there's just so much documentation that I can't figure out how to load and query some arbitrary XML data. How can I load an xml file into Virtuoso, and query it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start with the Virtuoso manual, [Chapter 15. XML Support](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/ch-webandxml/).

If you can't what you're looking for there, please bring your Virtuoso-specific questions to the [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com), where you'll find many other Virtuoso users as well as members of the Development team.